# Como crear un arreglo de documentos con javascript y enviarlos a PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un problema. Tengo que enviar un formulario que permite adjuntar múltiples documentos. Cada `<input type="file">` da la opción de agregar mas documentos.

Mi duda es, quiero procesar ese formulario con `JavaScript` y luego enviarlo a `php` para registrar la información en mi BD. Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Pensaba crear un arreglo de los `files` mediante el atributo `name` y recorriéndolos con la función `map` en un `array` o bien crear un arreglo con todos los `temp_name` en un arreglo.

Este es mi formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y actualmente en `javascript` lo proceso de esta forma:

```
function registroSolicitud(){

    var datosSolicitud = new FormData($( "#form-solicitud" )[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/centro/panel/controller/controlador_solicitud.php",
        data: datosSolicitud,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
    
    return false;
}
```

El problema es que si lo hago de esta manera me llegan los `<input type="file">` a `PHP`.

Comment: Perdón, no es eso lo que buscas? El título dice que quieres eso...

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta amigo

Comment: Dices _El problema es que si lo hago de esta manera me llegan los a PHP._ y el título pregunta cómo crear algo y enviarlos a PHP. No es claro qué es lo que quieres y por qué es diferente a lo que está pasando. Sé más claro en la pregunta y edítala, por favor

Comment: Si cada `input` tiene un `name` diferente, en `PHP` los debes recibir de acuerdo a este `name` por separado. Pero si los `input` tienen el mismo `name` como un arreglo, ejemplo: `name="adjuntos[]"`, `PHP` los recibe como tal y debes usar un ciclo para recorrerlos. Tal como dice @Alfabravo , faltan detalles en tu pregunta para que sea clara.

Comment: Tal como los estás enviando con `ajax` está bien. si deseas ver lo que te está llegando a `PHP`, utiliza `print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: Si mas bien el problema era como crear un arreglo, intentare hacer la manera que mencionas @DjCrazy para poder recibir el arreglo en PHP y recorrerlo mas bien mi duda era como crear un arreglo de files y recibirlo en PHP haciendo uso de Javascript

Comment: @DjCrazy Tenias razon ya recibi el arreglo de archivos unicamente haciendo uso de adjuntos[] al parecer me complique la vida de mas, o mas bien me revolví solo, me gustaría marcar tu comentario como respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si cada `input` tiene un `name` diferente, en `PHP` los debes recibir de acuerdo a este name por separado. Pero si los `input` tienen el mismo `name` como un arreglo, ejemplo: `name="adjuntos[]"`, `PHP` los recibe como tal y debes usar un ciclo para recorrerlos.

El `input` quedaría mas o menos así:

```
<input type="file" name="adjunto[]">
```

Tal como los estás enviando con `ajax` está bien. Si deseas ver lo que te está llegando a `PHP`, utiliza `print_r($_FILES);`