# jQuery POST falla al enviar una imagen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario para un registro, el cual contiene varios inputs para el nick, email, password y recientemente una imagen. Hay un botón de submit que no se ejecuta directamente, si no que el evento es atrapado con jquery y detenido ```event.preventDefault```

Obtengo la imagen de la siguiente manera:
   `const imgDoc = $("#input-img")[0].files;`

La petición es la siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: `/register`,
data: { email, nick, password, img },
success: function () {
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
},
error: function () {
  $("form span:last-child").css("display", "block");
},
});
```

Siendo img = imgDoc

El error que arrojaes el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede ser? Hay una respuesta a esta misma pregunta o una muy parecida, pero no logro entender la solución. Por sí ayuda lo dejo aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872448/jquery-post-blob-object-gives-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation

He probado varias soluciones más:

Incluirle a la petición ajax
`mimeType: 'image'`
Y formar el formData de la siguente manera:
`var datosSolicitud = new FormData(document.getElementById("input-img"))`;

Pero sigue sin funcionar y salta el siguiente error:

```
'Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
```

Comment: Ya intentaste con `FormData()`?

Comment: Si uso: ``` let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("myImg", img); ```

y en la petición pongo '  data: formData ', me sale el error de Ilegal invocation

Comment: Si es un formulario y estas usando `formData()` es innecesario tratar de agregar las imágenes con `.append` ya que `formData()` recoge todos los campos _siempre y cuando estén bien maquetados en el HTML_. Revisa esta [pregunta y su respectiva respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501236/como-crear-un-arreglo-de-documentos-con-javascript-y-enviarlos-a-php) para que te des una idea de cómo funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, podrías hacerlo con javascript puro.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form"),
button = document.getElementById("btn");

button.onclick = () =>{
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhr.open("POST", "/register");
  xhr.onload = ()=>{
    //window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
    console.log("success")
  }
  xhr.onerror = ()=>{
    //form.style.display = "block"
    console.log("error")
  }
  let newForm = new FormData(form);
  xhr.send(newForm);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="files" type="file">
  <input name="texto" type="text" placeholder="Escribe algo...">
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Espero que te ayude este código, yo por mi parte no soy de usar librerías, ya que son muy limitadas.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás enviando datos con un `<form>` entonces tienes que crear un formData

**Ejemplo:**

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");

const formData = new FormData(form);


$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: `/register`,
  data: formData,
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  success: function() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/login";
  },
  error: function() {
    $("form span:last-child").css("display", "block");
  },
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: He reproducido tu ejemplo exacto (cogiendo el id verdadero del form) pero sigue sin funcionar.

Error:
*Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation*

¿Da igual la estructura que tenga el html del form?